# Error running heroku locally, using the scala example

Tags: scala, heroku

I'm following along the introduction to heroku using scala. At the pint where I'm supposed to run the app locally ([link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#run-the-app-locally)) I get the following error.

```
PS E:\heroku_test\scala-getting-started> heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | [warn] application - Logger configuration in conf files is deprecated and has no effect. Use a logback configur
ation file instead.
web.1  | [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
web.1  | [error] c.z.h.HikariConfig - when specifying driverClassName, jdbcUrl must also be specified
web.1  | Oops, cannot start the server.








web.1  | Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
web.1  | Factory.java:62)
web.1  | stMethod.java:53)
web.1  | at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
web.1  | a:199)
```

I suspect it's something very simple but I couldn't find the error message in google. Also all the previous steps in the tutorial went exactly as expected.

EDIT:
From application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}
```

Procfile.windows

```
web: target\universal\stage\bin\play-getting-started.bat
```

Comment: Can you post the `db.default` entries in your `conf/application.conf` file? And can you post the contents of your `Procfile.windows`?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing DATABASE_URL from your environment. You can see that this guy `db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}` is trying to use it.

So before starting "activator run" or running "heroku local web -f Procfile.windows" (or something else you start the local server with), you need to "set" a link to the Postgres you want to use.

This works for quick local hack (first install Postgres locally, it asks you to set the postgres user's password):

```
set DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:<PASSWORD>@localhost:5432/<DB_NAME>
```

, where  is the one you set when installing, and  the name of the database inside Postgres you want to be used (create one there using psql).

After this the server runs.